# Trying to getText() from EditText box in Android, but nullPointerException being thrown

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to get text from two EditText fields, which I will then convert to an integer value and execute more code based off. Here is what my code is so far from my onCreate method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            EditText timer = (EditText)findByViewId(R.id.editText2);
            EditText beeps = (EditText)findByViewId(R.id.editText1);
            try{
                int length =        Integer.valueOf(timer.getText().toString());
                int beepRepeat = Integer.valueOf(beeps.getText().toString());
                Log.d("onClick","starting alarm");
                initializeAlarm(length, beepRepeat);//(length,    beepRepeat);
            }
            catch (Exception numberFormatException){
                Log.d("Catch","Caught number format exception");
                //Log.d("Catch",timer.getText().toString());
                //Log.d("Catch",beeps.getText().toString());
                initializeAlarm(2,3);
            };
        }
    });
}
```

However, I have an error thrown at 
    Log.d("Catch",timer.getText().toString());
Why on earth would I be getting an error there! All I am doing is printing the text as a string. Here is the error
java.lang.nullPointerException
and thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

Does anyone know why my getText() would be throwing a nullPointerException?

EDIT: Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" >

    </EditText>
```

EDIT: Here is information from the numberFormatException error

```
01-21 00:08:53.789: W/System.err(325): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 00:08:53.800: W/System.err(325):  at com.example.americancheesecakesupreme5000.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:31)
01-21 00:08:53.800: W/System.err(325):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-21 00:08:53.811: W/System.err(325):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-21 00:08:53.811: W/System.err(325):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-21 00:08:53.820: W/System.err(325):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-21 00:08:53.820: W/System.err(325):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-21 00:08:53.830: W/System.err(325):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-21 00:08:53.830: W/System.err(325):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 00:08:53.830: W/System.err(325):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-21 00:08:53.840: W/System.err(325):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-21 00:08:53.840: W/System.err(325):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-21 00:08:53.840: W/System.err(325):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT: My problem was I declared by EditText by calling Find**ByViewId** rather than Find**ViewByID**, which apparently compiled and ran fine, for whatever reason...

Comment: can you post your layout file: activity_main.xml

Comment: Integer.valueOf(timer.getText().toString()); ..what you have enter here..

Comment: You have written ` Log.d("Catch",timer.getText().toString());` this is catch block. Where did you get the exception at first place?

Comment: @sachy I get the exception at that line, as I suppose the error it (presumably) throws at the previous lines is taken care of by the catch(Exception numberFormatException)?

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities that causes the NullPointerException:

1. Your activity_mail.xml does not have `editText1` or `editText2` declared. Please check your layout file.
2. Your edit text presents, but one of them (or both) does not have any text input. In this case editText.getText() will return null. You should perform a validation before passing the data for integer parsing. For example:

   ```
   int length = 0;
   if(timer.getText()!=null)
           length = Integer.parseInt(timer.getText().toString());
   ```

**EDIT:**

Please use `Integer.parseInt()` instead of `Integer.valueOf()`, since `valueOf()` returns an `Integer` object, not `int`.

Comment: I posted my relevant activity_main.xml code, do you see any errors there?

Comment: @StephenArsenault no, so please try to do the validation for both `timer` and `beeps` as stated in my answer.

Comment: @HabibZare You can always choose not to perform any action if `getText()` returns null. At instance, if getText() returns null, show a `Toast` message asking the user to input all information required, and then call `return;` to finish the `onClick()` method.

Comment: It fixes my error when I use the validation, but I still don't get any useful output from my EditText boxes. I still need to be able to enter a number in the emulator. This means I must have an error between my XML and my Java R.id.editText2?

Comment: @StephenArsenault Do you mean that the soft keyboard does not show up when you click on the EditText in emulator?

Comment: No, the keyboard shows up and I am able to edit the text in the boxes, it doesn't accept decimals in the "Beep number" box as it is supposed to. But when I click run, it either acts as if both inputs are 0 or throws an exception (with the validation you suggested thrown in).

Comment: @StephenArsenault How can I missed that! `Integer.valueOf(string)` returns an `Integer` object, which does not work in your case. I have changed my answer using `Integer.parseInt(string)`, which returns `int`. This should fix your problem.

Comment: I already had it as a parseInt before, I just changed it to valueOf in hopes that it would help something. Still no luck!

Comment: @StephenArsenault Now this is weird. Have you tried to use parseInt back, together with the validation above? Please print the stacktrace of the `NumberFormatException` to your logcat, and paste it here :)

Comment: I don't see a logcat entry for NumberFormatException. It clearly reaches that point, as it prints my log.d("Catch","Caught NumberFormatException"), but I don't see where it would mention the NumberFormatException itself... And yes I did try changing to parseInt and running again

Comment: @StephenArsenault You need to call `numberFormatException.printStackTrace();` inside the catch block.

Comment: I have edited the log into my original post, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @StephenArsenault What is line 31 of your `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: I solved it! My problem was I declared the EditText fields with FindByViewId, when I should have been using FindViewById. What a tiny, stupid little error!

Comment: You got me one this one...Anyway, glad that you have your problem solved!